# Limit on WMIC requests from a Windows Service

Tags: windows, python, windows-service, wmi

Does anyone know if there is limit on how many `wmic` requests Windows can handle simultaneously if they are originating from a Windows service? The reason I'm asking is because my application fails when too many simultaneous requests have been initiated. I don't get any data back from the application.

However, If I compile the Python application and run it as a stand alone application all will work fine.

The wmic calls are looking like this:

```
subprocess.Popen("wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory get CommittedBytes", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This makes me wonder, is there a limit Windows Services and what they can perform? I mean, if the `.exe` file can handle all requests, then it must be something to do with the fact that I have compiled it as a Windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, I found an answer to this question, finally. The reason why this is happening is because Windows can't write to `stdout/stderr` using a Windows service, you can get around this problem by using a temporary file.